# How to go back two days from a date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I wrote an SQL query that allows me to get the sales of certain stores.
My query runs every mornings and I would like to get the sales from 2 days ago at runtime.

For example if my query runs tomorrow morning, on 08/12, I would like to have the sales whose value in the column `"GP_HEURECREATION"` starts with "20200612", to have all the sales of the whole day.

The `GP_HEURECREATION` column has a format like this: `"20200612 00:00:00"` and is of the `DATE` type.

I tried with `NOW()` and `DATEADD(`) but I have 2018 values that stand out for example.
How can I get the values only two days before the query is executed?

```
SELECT 
    T_ETABLISSEMENT, ET1.ET_LIBELLE AS C1, GL_ETABLISSEMENT, 
    GP_HEURECREATION, GP_REFINTERNE, GL_CODEARTICLE, 
    LIBDIM2, LIBDIM1, GL_QTEFACT, GL_PUTTC, 
    (GL_TOTALHT * GP_COTATIONDOS) AS TOTALHTDEV, GL_DPR, GL_DEVISE, 
    GL_NATUREPIECEG, GA_LIBELLE 
FROM 
    GCLIGNEARTDIM  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PGI_LOOKUP(TTETABLISSEMENT) ET1 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT = ET1.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
WHERE 
    (GP_HEURECREATION <= DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE())
    AND (GL_NATUREPIECEG = "FFO") 
    AND GL_ETABLISSEMENT = "20897", "10519", "20267", "26451", "20269", "26078", "28047", "20900", "28085", "24984", "27113", "20268", "19994", "28450", "26876", "24063", "18066", "3220"
ORDER BY 
    GP_REFINTERNE
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's a SQL monitor directly integrated in my POS software

Comment: @Patrick62: (1) Date functions are database specific. You need to figure out the database product that you are running. What happens with you run `select version()`? (2) What is the datatype of column `GP_HEURECREATION`?

Comment: sql monitor and your software can use any dbms, is it MYSQL  , Postgres , Oracle or Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: The column  `GP_HEURECREATION` is of type DATE. I'm not sure of the type of my database, how can I know it with a query? @GMB

Comment: @Patrick62: just try and run `select version()`, and copy the output here.

Comment: I get an error message when I execute this request in the program monitor...

Comment: Error converting TODO field from a datatob to a tob (/@@EXCEPTION@@.NET[-1]/CbpExceptionInfo_[0]/CbpExceptionInfo_[0]): The object reference is not defined to an instance of an object

Comment: if GP_HEURECREATION is DATE (without time), you might try: GP_HEURECREATION <= DATE(sysdate() - INTERVAL 2 DAY )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your existing query suggests SQL Server. If you want records that belong to day -2, you can do:

```
where gp_heurecreation >= dateadd(day, -2, convert(date, getdate()))
  and gp_heurecreation <  dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()))
```

If `gp_heurecreation` has no time component (in SQL Server, that's a `date` datatype), this is simpler:

```
where gp_heurecreation = dateadd(day, -2, convert(date, getdate()))
```